# equivalent of betadist of excel in python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

what is the equivalent of `=BETADIST(0.5,8,3)` of excel in python ?

I have tried using scipy.stats and unable to achieve same results..

Comment: " have tried using scipy.stats and unable to achieve same results" what _specifically_ have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? A question should include a [mcve] so that we can offer specific answers and help

Answer (score 2):

As G. Anderson points out this depends on your specific application. For a start you can define a beta distribution in scipy, draw some samples and and plot them as follows:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the true distribution parameters
a_true = 2
b_true = 3

# define a beta distribution and draw some samples
beta_true = scipy.stats.beta(a=a_true, b=b_true)
y_obs = beta_true.rvs(size=500)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

# plot the samples and PDF
plt.plot(x, beta_true.pdf(x), lw=2, color="r", label='PDF beta_true')
plt.hist(y_obs, bins=20, density=True, label="samples")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

If what you want is to infer parameters for a stochastic process that you assume follows a beta distribution you could use pymc:

```
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az

model = pm.Model()

with model:
    # priors for a and b
    a = pm.HalfNormal("a", sigma=1)
    b = pm.HalfNormal("b", sigma=1)
    
    # observed RV
    y = pm.Beta("y", alpha=a, beta=b, observed=y_obs)
    
    tr = pm.sample(1000, tune=2000, chains=4, cores=8, return_inferencedata=True)
```

```
>>> az.summary(tr, round_to=4)

    mean    sd  hdi_3%  hdi_97%     mcse_mean   mcse_sd     ess_bulk    ess_tail    r_hat
a   1.9152  0.1089  1.7109  2.1217  0.0035  0.0025  973.6684    1550.1573   1.0024
b   2.9142  0.1751  2.5962  3.2444  0.0057  0.0040  949.3716    1590.1557   1.0036
```

```
# estimated beta distribution
a_hat, b_hat = az.summary(tr, round_to=4)["mean"]
beta_estimated = scipy.stats.beta(a=a_hat, b=b_hat)

# plot the PDFs of the true and the estimated distributions of RV "y"
plt.hist(y_obs, bins=20, density=True, label="samples")
plt.plot(x, beta_estimated.pdf(x), lw=2, label='PDF beta_estimated')
plt.plot(x, beta_true.pdf(x), lw=2, color="r", label='PDF beta_true')
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("Density")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please specify your question so we can give specific advice in return.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions in SciPy that provide the same calculation as Excel's [`BETADIST(x, alpha, beta)`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/betadist-function-49f1b9a9-a5da-470f-8077-5f1730b5fd47): the function [`scipy.special.btdtr(alpha, beta, x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.btdtr.html) and the `cdf` method of the distribution [`scipy.stats.beta`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html).  (Note that `btdtr` has parameters in a different order.)

```
In [13]: from scipy.special import btdtr

In [14]: from scipy.stats import beta
```

Either of these computes the same result (other than a tiny numerical difference that is the result of floating point imprecision):

```
In [15]: btdtr(8, 3, 0.5)
Out[15]: 0.054687500000000014

In [16]: beta.cdf(0.5, 8, 3)
Out[16]: 0.0546875
```

If all you need is the CDF for the standard beta distribution, then use `scipy.special.btdtr`, because `beta.cdf(0.5, 8, 3)` is 50 times slower than `btdtr(8, 3, 0.5)`:

```
In [18]: %timeit btdtr(8, 3, 0.5)
13.5 µs ± 222 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit beta.cdf(0.5, 8, 3)
673 µs ± 16.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

If you will eventually need the PDF, or a function to fit the beta distribution to data, or you need to set the bounds of the support to arbitrary points, then look that `scipy.stats.beta`.